# Calling stored procedure with multiple select statement in codeinginter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

in model i have tried this 
but it returns only first select statement value but procedure has more than one select statement

```
    $query=$this->db->query("CALL finishingformula($formulaid,$versionnumber,$status)");
    $res   = $query->result();     
    foreach($res as $row)
     {
         echo $row->formula_id;

     }
```

Comment: something is wrong with your stored procedure

Comment: it returns all the query results in phpmyadmin